Docker: Having local domain names for local containers
I am currently doing a little bit of devops to have a better process handling on my work, and i have been trying for couple hours straight to somehow have some private local domains for my docker containers, instead of going through localhost:port.
I have been trying to configure traefik, nginx, and dnsmasq to make what i'm wanting but i'm not even sure if i need a custom dns or a reverse proxy or both.
The one i use the most is traefik but always with paid domains and it's working great.
I have read a lot of forums, and tutos, to try and do this but i seems like everything that i have found is not working or i'm doing wrong.
Exactly what I'm trying to do is for exemple:

Locally accessing one of my docker on the localhost:8069 with the url http://docker.dev and another on the localhost:3000 with http://otherdocker.dev.
Having all the config in one or two docker compose, ex: 1 containing the app and the network, or 1 containing the app and 1 containing the network for all apps.

I dont really care if the end url looks like http://docker.dev or like http://local.dev/docker as long as i can set specific domains/subdomains for my dockers.
Some precision about my setup:
The whole point is to run multiple odoo dockers without needind to relog in each each time i switch the browser page beacause of connexion token linked to url localhost.
Also i wanted to be able to have a lot of formated url to access each port of theses dockers to get specific apps like http://odoo17.dev + http://shell17.dev etc.
If someone knows how to do this without going through a paid domain name and opening my setup to the web i'd be gratefull to get a couple hints.
Thanks

So personally if i was trying this. I would add entries to /etc/host on my local machine to point these domains to 127.0.0.1 and then setup nginx in docker compose to listen on port 80. In the nginx config you can have different blocks for each domain and just revrese proxy them to the respective docker service.

Thanks for the suggestion, i did try this but it's not very convenient as i need to edit the nginx config file and reload the docker each time i add a container. Traefik let you set labels in the new container wich is way more convenient. Is there a similar way of providing config to nginx reverse proxy ?

You can use that anything that ends in localhost is sent to the local machine. Then you don't need to edit hosts files etc.
So for instance to run 2 containers behind Traefik, you could have a docker compose file like this
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '8888:8080'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.docker.localhost`)"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`nginx.docker.localhost`)"

Then traffic to whoami.docker.localhost is routed to one container and traffic to nginx.docker.localhost is routed to the other.

Hello, thanks a lot for this answers it seem to work well as long as i keed the ".docker.localhost", but if i do change it to ".localhost" it doesn"t work anymore, is there a way to change it to ".dev" to make it shorter to type ?

You can use any domain names you like, but then you have to edit your hosts file or set it up in your local DNS server if you have one. localhost is special and is part of the RFC, so it's nice and easy to use.

I tried with just ".localhost" but it doesn't work at all. Maybe it is because docker containers are not directly hosted on 127.0.0.1 and that ".docker.localhost" does redirect to correct ip. With editing the host file what should i add to use the ".dev" domain ?

You'd need to add 127.0.0.1 my.domain.dev for each domain you want to use.

Yeah, it's pretty inconvenient, thanks for the answer, i'll stick with ".docker.localhost" then =)
